# Creating own character set causes crash

Tags: swift, character, decimal, nscharacterset

I'm using this piece of code to limit user input regarding the keyboard.

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn     range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.init(charactersIn: ".0123456789")
    let characterSet = NSCharacterSet(charactersIn: string)

    return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet as CharacterSet)
}
```

but my program crashes when I enter any character.
[image]

Update 2:
So 99.9% of this solution works great, unfortunately the period/decimal point does not register. Unsure why this is happening?

Comment: should be `CharacterSet(charactersIn:` not `NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in Swift, there are multiple issues on this matter on the Swift issue tracker: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3311, https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3667

Until this has been fixed, you can workaround this problem by using the following extension:

```
extension CharacterSet {

    func isSupersetOf(other: CharacterSet) -> Bool {
        return CFCharacterSetIsSupersetOfSet(self as CFCharacterSet, (other as NSCharacterSet).copy() as! CFCharacterSet)
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that you need to change your `characterSet` variable from type `NSCharacterSet` to `CharacterSet` to be able to use that extension in your example.

Comment: Excuse the ignorance as i've never used extensions before. is this placed below viewDidLoad?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is a method on `UIViewController`, you can not define an extension on that level - no.

Comment: I made a new file by itself. However, now I'm able to enter any character into my text field.

Comment: No, you need to put the extension outside of you class - above the opening statement `class ClassName {`,  below the closing bracket of the `class`, or even in an own file, as you see fit.